# Number declaration in Pascal

Tags: pascal

I have an old program written in Pascal here, and after I have never learned Pascal, I do not understand everything. I have in my program several assignments like `asdf = $03A2`. What does the `$` mean? Usually, there is no sign in front of the assigned numbers.

Comment: It means it's a hexadecimal number. Normally, Pascal assumes decimal, like most other languages. And like most other languages, some kind of prefix is required to indicate a different radix for the constant value (hex, binary, octal).

Comment: Note that $ is a feature of Borland derived dialects. IIRC the extended pascal standard did it differently, Standard Pascal didn't have the feature.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort yes that is correct. Extended Pascal would use, for example, `16#03A2` for a hexadecimal constants. Both of these formats are supported by GNU Pascal.

Comment: Unfortunately, GNU Pascal itself seems to be no longer supported :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $ represents a hexadecimal number. If $ is not there, it means that is a number in base 10.